# Drawing with your fingers

Tags: java, android, drawing

I found this little sample code, to do drawing with your finger:
http://marakana.com/tutorials/android/2d-graphics-example.html

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Point point : points) {
        canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 5, paint);
    }
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = event.getX();
    point.y = event.getY();
    points.add(point);
    invalidate();
    Log.d(TAG, "point: " + point);
    return true;
}
```

I was looking through it, and saw that they are adding points to an ArrayList, then looping through the ArrayList, this doesn't seem like it is a very optimized approach to this. Is there a better approach or is this a good approach?

After testing on my Samsung GS3, I colored the whole screen in with a circle size of 20, and the closer it got to full color the slower it took to draw, and then circles were becoming spaced out.

Comment: You're question isn't very specific. It would be better if you could post some code.

Comment: You may be expecting too much from a tutorial on `onDraw`.

Comment: it depends on what you want to draw : paths , circles, squares and etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, this makes sense in this example.

He loops through all the points he wants to draw.
This means he adds every point to the array, so he can loop through all the objects at once.

You'll often see this in game programming.

---

This is also very expandable.

1. You can add as many points as you want
2. It supports polymorphism
3. You don't have to make variables for multiple points > Less code

Comment: I believe he asking more about optimisation.. Continually adding points to a list is a bad idea. IE points could be removed if they are no longer visible, or a point could be ignored if it already exists in the list

Comment: @AlanFoster Yes, of course you'd have to make a validation check before adding them to the array. Otherwise you'll be out of memory pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

First, use stroke (not circles) to draw the line. Second, approximate. Here's a summary:

1. Change `Paint` to use a stroke with `width=5`. That reduces the need to draw so many circles.
2. Pick a threshold, for example `3px` after which you'll add a point in `onTouch()`.

   ```
   if (Math.abs(previousX - event.getX()) < THRESHOLD
           && Math.abs(previousY - event.getY()) < THRESHOLD) {
       return;
   }
   previousX = event.getX();
   previousY = event.getY();
   // drawing update goes here
   ```

   This should reduce number of (unnoticeable) points.
3. Use `Picture` or `Path` class to draw the line to, and use `Canvas.drawPath()` or `Canvas.drawPicture()`. This, especially for large number of points, will really speed the drawing since all drawing commands will be passed to the internal drawing function in one call.
4. Simplify the shape at need. For example, you could delete eldest points (which would be a perfect case to use [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)), use the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) which is pretty easy to implement, gives good results and has complexity of `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: Does your threshold example work? Shouldn't it be a logical `and` instead of logical `or` ?

Comment: @AlanFoster yes, of course you're right. I've updated the code in my answer.